# How to define overloaded Curry function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, typescript-generics, currying

I have these 2 curry functions below. `curry2` receives a function with 2 parameters and returns a curried function and `curry3` receives a function with 3 parameters and returns the curried function.

```js
type Curry2 = <A, B, Z>(f: (a: A, b: B) => Z)
  => (a: A)
  => (b: B)
  => Z
const curry2: Curry2 = f => a => b => f(a, b)

type Curry3 = <A, B, C, Z>(f: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => Z)
  => (a: A)
  => (b: B)
  => (c: C)
  => Z
const curry3: Curry3 = f => a => b => c => f(a, b, c)
```

I want to define a one general `curry` function in a most possible type-safe way that curry the passed function `f` (regardless of number of parameters `f` receives).

I try to do this with Function Overloading in typescript with for example maximum number of parameters for `f`, but couldn't find a way.

Is this possible to do this in typescript?

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, so let's think about JavaScript alone for a minute. How would you hope to implement such a `curry` function?  How does JavaScript know exactly how many parameters a function should receive?  I mean, JS supports [variadic functions via rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).  What would `function sum(...args: number[]) { return args.reduce((a, b)=>a+b,0) }; const curriedSum = curry(sum);` produce?

Comment: Like, the only thing I can think of that actually has a chance of working in the face of possibly variadic functions is a curry like `curry(fn)(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)()` where the last empty call tells it that you're done. That could look like [this playground link code](https://tsplay.dev/mArJ1W). I'm happy to write that up as an answer but I don't know if it meets your needs. Let me know.

Comment: Or you pass in a number-of-parameters argument manually, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m36xLN).  Any indication of what direction you're thinking of going would be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any
```

First we create a type that maps over each argument and carries the return type recursivley

```
// Create a type signature for a curried function:
// e.g. Curry<(a:string,b:number)=>string> -> (a:string)=>(b:string)=>string
type Curry<Fn extends AnyFunc> =
    Parameters<Fn> extends [infer FirstArg, ...infer Rest]
    ? (arg: FirstArg) => Curry<(...args: Rest) => ReturnType<Fn>>
    : ReturnType<Fn>

// more examples
type x = Curry<(arg1: number, arg2: number) => string> //  (arg: number) => (arg: number) => string
type y = Curry<(arg1: number, arg2: number, args: number[]) => string> // (arg: number) => (arg: number) => (arg: number[]) => string
```

The next step is a bit wanky (you should alway think twice before you cast a type), but in this case it should be ok for the most use cases

You can create a recursive function that aggregates every argument until the length of the args of the passed function are equal to the length of the aggregated args.
By type casting the function body to any and providing a Returntype. You can force TS to apply the previous defined `Curry` type

```
function curry<T extends AnyFunc, TAgg extends unknown[]>(func: T, agg?: TAgg): Curry<T> {
    const aggregatedArgs = agg ?? []
    if (func.length === aggregatedArgs.length) return func(...aggregatedArgs)
    return ((arg: any) => curry(func, [...aggregatedArgs, arg])) as any
}

const c = curry((a: string, b: string) => console.log(a, b))
c("a")
c("b")("a")
c("b")("a")("d") // invalid

const b = curry((a: string, b: number) => console.log(a, b))

b("b")("a") // invalid
b("b")(1)("d") // invalid
b("b")(1)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEAkFMBsAdIE6gC4E96gGYHslowMbYB2AzsggIYCWxyAUPpKAILGoBiArsQaALygAFADoxlBAHNSALlCV2AbQC6ASgEA+ee3r0QoALKVYpUNgBuiUJEoEAFvKlcAtpDraAJqAISE1SKbIdswIkMhcCMQo6MyMMaAAwhEIqAA8HFGQAB7Ibh6mbJw8BFr89KAVoAAKEpSuuQik6cRa2bnE+aCKtJhWHNSNyCxSADSgYiI9VgBKAcjK5ZUA-MISknL9g8OS6vxaSQgpqaLiUrKgs+S7WrPhkQAqMc0aGosVcrcRxI-wz7pMoCyAkSyTSQjWAEY5MQXAAjRBjNYAJmhcMQ11A5D8xEkWn0qykqOc8IQGPBhNAMOJ6M0mIotEkcQwqGBByO5MkUMpaIQiKkKO51N5jmkRJJKgxWIZeLAHLFNL2BPWgpJZLW8oQEtpUpxun0QWopkN8lAsOoyFAAHcFABrVBjWFcC3mzF2bBcaBeeFmG1YXAoYKgZzYcigLikZg+COkeiYYrIagkbyg1L3aw5PIFdjcXhje4sSSSdPtTo8G3EbCW4gqDRCOO8OT3RGFpaNgs7ORstL3LQAbze3hIocohdCkkouQ821MghHRaWKxUA+omGE9YIImgbkkQQE-Fno8g48n08326C6lCdyi65OIjnY4nkCnZ1UA6vX2Ecu0qAxBFBdbFGMigTA+R5Pi+0h8pIajqJQpgKKg9AAL66EQZAWnwgj-ocqBCOCcg6pIDqEfSOJ-kO2Bbpu2CSOCDqqG+BBCAARJQLFMaxsIcax7GcSx3GqLxPEsR4HGgPotDmJQ0DUB4aFDhasLAjhKT4ZQpHYsRpoahRZBUZANF0ZQDFvvQsJcSJfESWAUkyXJ5mWUJEJCaJ4mScQ0myfJFkCTxLmgPQQA)